# Is there any way to create a world the size of the Moon or of Arrakis with a breathable atmosphere?

Tags: science-based

Part One: Introduction

Stephen H. Dole, in *Habitable Planets for Man*, 1964 calcualted an approximate lower limit for the escape velocity of a planet that could retain oxygen for billions of years.   Dole also calculated how the masses of terrestrial planets correlated to their sizes, densites, surface gravity, and escape velocity.

[https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf[1]](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf%5B1%5D)

According to Dole there would be very little wiggle room for a terrestrial planet to be much less massive or smaller in size than his minimum and still be able to retain an atmosphere.  Dole didn't believe there could be tiny planets which extremely high average density that might have high enough escape velocity to retain a breathable atmosphere for billions of years.

Part Two:  The Size of Planet Arrakis in *Dune*.

When I was thirteen I used a ruler to measure short lengths along Smaug's curved body in Tolkien's illustration "Conversation with Smaug" and added them to find that Smaug was 40 times as long as the distance across his nostrils.  Since Smaug was unable to insert his nostrils into a doorway five feet high, I deduced that Smaug should have been at least 200 feet long.

Yesterday I found my hardbound copy of Frank Herbert's *Dune*.  Decades ago, I calculated that the planet Arrakis or Dune should have approximately the diameter of Earth's moon.  So I used the data in my copy to redo the calculations again.

Using the map of the north polar regions of Dune on pages 486-87, and the notes to it on page 488, I calcuated the circumference of Dune.  The note on Carthag says "About 200 kilometers northeast of Arrakeen".

Yesterday I measured Arrakeen and Carthag as about 18 mm apart on that map, while the distance from 60 degrees north latitude across the north pole to the opposite 60 degrees north latitude was about 135 mm.  So 60 degrees of latitude equals about 135 mm on the map and thus about 2.25 mm per degree.  With about 18 mm per about 200 kilometers, there are about 11.11 kilometers per mm.  So one degree equals about 29.9976 kilometers or rounded off to 30 kilometers. So the circumference of the planet Arrakis should be about 10,800 kilometers which equals a radius of about 1,718.8733 kilometers, as compared to 1,737.4 kilometers for the Moon.

There is another copy of the Dune map on the back cover.  Today I measured that Carthag is about 21 or 22 mm from Arrakeen on that map, and 60 degrees of latitude is about 188 mm.

So one mm is about 9.0909 to 9.523 kilometers, and 60 degrees of latitude is about 188 mm, making about 3.133 mm per degree.  Thus there should be about 28.48 to 29.89 kilometers per degree.  That makes the circumference of planet Arrakis or Dune 10,252.8 to 10,928 kilometers, and thus it's radius should be about 1,631.784 to 1,739.245 kilometers.

Luna, or the Moon, has a radius of 1,737.4 kilometers, and Europa has a radius of 1,560.8 kilometers.

I wonder if the size, radius, diameters, mass, density, surface gravity, or escape velocity of Arrakis is mentioned in any Dune novels.   If I remember correctly, the *Dune Encyclopedia* describes Arrakis as much more normal sized for a planet habitable for humans.

I think that any sort of parody of *Dune* should make Arrakis as small as the map indicates, and make its habitability despite that small size an important plot element, a mystery which most people ignore but turns out to be vitally important.

Part Three: The Question to be Answered.

On page 54 of *Habitable Planets for Man*, Dole calcuated that a planet would need to have an escape velocity of at least 5 times the root-mean-square velocity of atomic oxygen to retain a breathable atmosphere for geological times spans, and thus at least 6.25 kilometers per second. Dole said that corresponded to a plent with 0.195 Earth mass, a radius of 0.63 Earth radius, and a surface gravity of 0.49 g.  But Dole believed that such a planet would be too small to form a breathable atmosphere.

Dole estimated two different minimum masses for a planet able to form a breathable atmosphere, 0.25 Earth mass and 0.58 Earth mass, and decided on pages 56 & 57 that a figure in between, about 0.4 Earth mass, would be the minimum requirement to produce a breathable atmospehere.

> This corresponds to a planet having a radius of 0.78 Earth radius and a surface gravity of 0.68 g.

Today scientists have more accurate values for the radii and masses and thus average densities, of many solar system bodies.  And they also have some values for the radii and masses and thus densities of terrestrial type planets in other systems.  So I wonder if there are any known terrestrial type planets, moons, or asteroids with much greater densities than Dole's calculations predict.

Is it possibly for a planet to form naturally out of sufficiently dense materials to have a radius of about 1,700 kilometers and and also a mass high enough to have an escape velocity over 6.25 kilometers per second?  If it is possible, how improbable would it be for such a planet to form?

And if it is not possible or extremely improbable for such a planet to form naturally, would it be possible for some highly advanced civilization to create such a planet by collecting dense metals from many solar systems to build the planet?

Or would such a hypothetical advanced civilization have to create it by using force fields to compress degenerate matter into the core of the planet and keep it compressed, so that if the force fields ever failed the planet would explode?

Or would even the most advanced civilization be unable to make a planet dense enough to have sufficient gravity naturally, thus requiring them to resort to using artificial gravity generators to enable the planet to retain its atmosphere, failure of the artifical gravity generators reulting in catastophic atmosphere loss?

Comment: Dune is a special case. We're not seeing very many photosynthesizers on it. The sandworms are responsible for oxygen, through some weird biological process.

Comment: If you don't need the atmosphere to last for stronomical timescales unattended, you don't need to have an escape velocity that high, though you may wind up needing  more atmosphere than Earth currently has to get the desired surface pressure.

Comment: [This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/39347) on Astronomy.SE is about the related subject of having liquid water on a planet, but it discusses atmosphere as well and might be a useful starting point.

Comment: (a) [Questions about 3rd party and/or commercial worlds are off-topic](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7336/40609), therefore all of the Dune-related portions of your question are irrelevant and, honestly, should be removed (you calculated sizes of anything based on artist's depictions?). (b) VTC:Needs Focus is because there should be one question. Happy to recant if you narrow this to just one question. (c) How on earth are we supposed to know what an advanced civ can or cannot do? "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Comment: @JBH "Questions about 3rd party" are off-topic in regards to in-universe explanations. A science-based question like "How a planet like Arrakis can hold to its atmosphere?" is perfectly valid, imho.

Comment: Although my personal impression is that this question is poorly focused. Everything about Arrakis here is just an aside and does not contribute to the main question asked.

Comment: @Alexander As badly as I might have put it, your observation is exactly my concern. It appears to add nothing to the question (but it does take a while to read through). Looking back on it, I suspect I quoted the policy as a way of lending credibility to the admonition to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Option #1: dense worlds

The Earth has mean density of 5.51 g/cm³, which, given its radius of 6,371 km produces 1 g of gravity on its surface. For a planet with the radius of 1,750 km, to get 0.68 g on surface, its average density should be about 13.5 g/cm³. This is a lot, but not so much that we need to seek solutions that involve degenerate matter. Under normal conditions, gold has density of 19.32 g/cm³, and osmium 22.6 g/cm³. The planet that we want would have a core that consists of heavy noble metals, instead of iron. Planet still can have enough iron to produce strong enough magnetic field. How this planet may form is another question, but once formed, it appears to be suitable to support life as we know it.

Option #2: ongoing processes

While it may be hard to keep gases from escaping the planet if it is as small and as warm as the Moon, we may suggest that some geological processes would continuously replenish atmosphere, compensating for the loss. Replenishment of molecular oxygen from the planetary crust may be difficult to explain, but other gases like carbon dioxide and methane would be realistic. Of course, planet's biosphere should be able to keep up with oxygen production.

Comment: Option # 2 needs a world dense enough to have an escape velocity of 6.125 kilometers per second, not a surface gravity of 0.68 g.  My question here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238096/how-large-is-the-planet-arrakis-in-dune  indicates that a much higher density would be needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Make the high atmosphere a lot colder** so it doesn't escape much.

At least in part, by making the whole climate somewhat colder. The planet being small can also result in higher temperature gradient.

See Titan - it has an atmosphere consisting of nitrogen (just as our own) and methane that is exactly as heavy as atomic oxygen. And yet it has surface pressure similar to Earth's.

The high atmosphere is heated mostly by solar wind (well, on Earth). Titan has the luxury of using the Saturn's magnetic field as a giant deflector. Your planet may as well have its own.